# How programatically detect Flash plugin is launched under Safe Mode in Safari browser?

Tags: actionscript-3, safari, flash

While Flash Plugin launched in Safari's Safe Mode it cannot save files on local file system. In some cases such attempt just hang the whole browser. The question is how to detect Safe Mode before trying to save file. I mean to detect from inside ActionScript application.

Comment: I don't know Safari's Safe Mode, but if JavaScript can know that, you can use [`ExternalInterface`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html) to pass the information to Flash ...

Comment: In Safari Safe Mode enabled for each plugin separately. So I think JavaScript isn't aware Flash Plugin sandbox settings.

Comment: I've discovered Flash Plugin reference in <window.navigator.plugins> collection but there is no mention of Safe Mode settings.